# merge all text files into one with filename in line

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing files with naming convention:

```
test.201506010000.csv
test.201506010005.csv
test.201506010010.csv
...
test.201506302355.csv
```

Each file keeps numerical value in it. I'd like to merge all files into one (with removal of source files, line by line) and also I'd like to put the date from filename before each line.

Desired target:

```
merged.csv

2015-06-01 00:00,<value_of_text.201506010000.csv>
2015-06-01 00:05,<value_of_text.201506010005.csv>
...
2015-06-30 23:55,<value_of_text.201506312355.csv>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the files, extracting the timestamp from the file name using parameter expansion.

```
for file in test.*.csv ; do
    time=${file#test.}        # Remove "test" on the left.
    time=${time%.csv}         # Remove ".csv" on the right.
    time=${time:0:4}-${time:4:2}-${time:6:2}' '${time:8:2}:${time:10:2}
    sed "s/^/$time,/" "$file" # Append time to each line of the file.
    rm "$file"                # This removes the original file. Have you made a backup?
done > one-file.csv
```

Comment: This is almost ok, but appends a date only to first line in every file. I didn't mentioned - single file may have multiple lines. I need it for all lines in all files. And also not appending a comma after the date
4th line must of above, must add ','

Comment: still something wrong.

I've two files:  'test.nfcapd.201506010000.csv' and  'test.nfcapd.201506010005.csv'
both of them have 4 lines of content.

merge.sh
'for file in *.csv ; do
    time=${file#count.nfcapd.}
    time=${time%.csv}
    time=${time:0:4}-${time:4:2}-${time:6:2}' '${time:8:2}:${time:10:2}','
    sed "s/^/$time,/" "$file"
done > merge.csv'

in result I have 16 lines in merge.csv
8 with correct result, but next 8 with strange appendix before the date field

'merg-e- :,'

Comment: @golazo: Don't process the output file. Use test*.csv, not just *. csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in test.*.csv; do printf "%s-%s-%s %s:%s,%s\n" ${file:5:4} ${file:9:2} ${file:11:2} ${file:13:2} ${file:15:2} $(cat $file) >>merged.csv; done
```